# Apache Flink. Streaming job can not continue processing messages because some threads of job could not recover state from latest successful checkpoint

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a flink streaming job which consumes messages from kafka topic and saves it to S3 storage using StreamingFileSink sink. Job run with parallelism of 10. At the beginning job was running without any exceptions for several days. However we have got stuck with processing messages, because 6 threads cannot recover state from latest successful checkpoint.
In UI we have next exception -

```
java.io.IOException: Recovering commit failed for object RMS/XXLM_RMS_BATCH_COMP_DPAC/2021-10-14--10/part-9-644. Object does not exist and MultiPart Upload 0005CE4D24D0D208 is not valid.
at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer.commitAfterRecovery(S3Committer.java:123)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.OutputStreamBasedPartFileWriter$OutputStreamBasedPendingFile.commitAfterRecovery(OutputStreamBasedPartFileWriter.java:218)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.commitRecoveredPendingFiles(Bucket.java:160)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.<init>(Bucket.java:127)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.restore(Bucket.java:466)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.DefaultBucketFactoryImpl.restoreBucket(DefaultBucketFactoryImpl.java:67)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.handleRestoredBucketState(Buckets.java:192)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.initializeActiveBuckets(Buckets.java:179)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.initializeState(Buckets.java:163)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSinkHelper.<init>(StreamingFileSinkHelper.java:75)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink.initializeState(StreamingFileSink.java:472)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:171)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorStateHandler.initializeOperatorState(StreamOperatorStateHandler.java:118)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:290)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:436)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:574)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:554)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:756)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:563)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSBadRequestException: Completing multipart commit on RMS/XXLM_RMS_BATCH_COMP_DPAC/2021-10-14--10/part-9-644: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: s entity tag. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidPart; Request ID: 4a52c48aed3bffc6; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null:InvalidPart: s entity tag. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidPart; Request ID: 4a52c48aed3bffc6; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:212)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:111)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$3(Invoker.java:260)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:317)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:256)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.finalizeMultipartUpload(WriteOperationHelper.java:222)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.completeMPUwithRetries(WriteOperationHelper.java:267)
at org.apache.flink.fs.s3hadoop.HadoopS3AccessHelper.commitMultiPartUpload(HadoopS3AccessHelper.java:95)
at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer.commitAfterRecovery(S3Committer.java:93)
... 22 more Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: s entity tag. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidPart; Request ID: 4a52c48aed3bffc6; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1811)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1395)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1371)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5062)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5008)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.completeMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:3490)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.lambda$finalizeMultipartUpload$1(WriteOperationHelper.java:229)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:109)
... 29 more
```

[Screen of running job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZHBB.png)

And if we look inside the bucket on S3 there are no files mentioned in error message, for instance part-9-644 or part-0-644 or part-5-644, but there are some temp files with such prefixes.

[List of objects in bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9JRJ.png)

Another thing that we want mention is that last checkpoint was failed with Exception: Checkpoint Coordinator is suspending.

[Checkpoints summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK6M0.png)

Has anybody faced the same problem? Or may be could explain the root cause of such situation?

Thanks.